# Process with protobuf ParseFromString crash

Tags: c++, crash, protocol-buffers

On production machine only I have a crash in a process. I was able to isolate this to a `ParseFromString` call. When `ParseFromString` isn't called the process doesn't crash. When called, process will crash eventually: not in `ParseFromString` but after several stack exits on the same thread (so I have pinpointed the exact crash location, where nothing interesting actually happens) so this probably seems to be a bad memory allocation problem. This does not reproduce in the lab nor on the production machine using `WinDbg`. Input to `ParseFromString` as seen in the pretty-print dump (clear text, not the actual binary input to the method) seems normal with no special characters or redundant spaces. The binary in the input `std::string` of-course has special characters.

I would like to have suggestions on how to continue investigating this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble.
The reason was: version of .lib isn't suitable dll. For example, to compile with release .lib file and to use debug dll file.
So, check exact version of lib and dll. Check your compile settings: don't mix debug code, with release libraries, etc.